# Finding users with "edit" and "delete" rights for Exchange Distribution Groups

Tags: shell, powershell, exchange-server

Is it possible to create a script that will find all the exchange distribution groups with a certain prefix (say "X_"), and find the users that can "edit" and "delete" this group?

I've managed to use the exchange console shell to return all the groups that start with "X_" with this script (look under this paragraph), and return who is listed as "managed by". But I still need to find the users that can "edit" and "delete" the group..

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Identity "X_*" |
    Format-Table Name, ManagedBy -Auto |
    Export-Csv -path "C:\Temp\Distribution Groups\New folder\Distribution Groups.csv" -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Have you tried the `Get-ADPermission` cmdlet ? (example use here : see http://nsfw.ibnmasud.com/find-send-as-rights-on-a-distribution-group/)

Comment: I'm fairly new to this, the distribution groups and exchange, I wasn't aware I could use this type of command on distribution groups in Exchange? 
I'll do some reading and try it out, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Also, the exchange servers in the environment are 2010, and this cmndlet only works for 2016, right? Is there an alternative that can be run on 2010?

Comment: The snippet was written for 2010, it seems. You will have to test it to make sure.

Comment: I tried this solution and a variation of the same, and it seems it's not easy getting what I needed. We ended up scrapping the attempt and calling it "not possibe". Thanks for the help though.